# Show Mongodb query projection in the Log

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

**(updated)**

I want to see the field restriction (projection) used in a query in the log, not just the query itself, so I can see exactly what's being requested. I've set 'vvvv=true' along with 'verbose=true' in the config file, so given a shell query;

```
db.col.find({},{Name:1}).count()
```

I can then see this in the log;

```
command: {"count":"col, query:{_id:23}, fields: {Name: 1.0}}}
```

However, the following query does NOT.

```
db.col.find({_id:23},{Name:1})
```

Nor am I seeing this through the C# driver when I use `Fields.Include` on the `MongoCursor`.

What am I missing?

Comment: are your sure about the log entry and the 1st query (with count)? Since you are finding with {} and the log entry shows query:{_id:23}.

Comment: You're right, but it doesn't matter which query. Either way, I don't see field restriction for find() in the log.

Comment: thats odd. i will try to reproduce it

Answer (score 1):

The MongoD server currently does not log the projection. There is a ticket in our JIRA for this: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-3129 — please vote for it if you want to show this is important to you.